# how to install wireless adapters and download any softwares from ubuntu software center

Tags: networking

My laptop is a Latitude d630 and I am running Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 but I had some problems like :

1. I cannot download any software through Ubuntu software center,
2. I cannot work with Internet through wireless adapter, but in Windows 7 I 
   can run wireless adapter and can access the Internet. My broadband W-Lan drivers are also installed.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 1. Download [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit] your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview. 2. Please tell us what you already tried to solve said problems and where you did get stuck.

Comment: Can you install software using apt?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Latitude D630, running Ubuntu. Windows is installed, but rarely booted. I have neither of your problems (you should only ask 1 question at a time - this enhances the ability of future users to find the question and **answer**.

To load the module needed to support WiFi on the Latitude D630,

```
sudo modprobe b43
```